# Google maps on the android application does not appear

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

Google maps on the android application does not appear. On the terminal it says E/location: enabled

E/location: enabled

[image]

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-display-locations-from-firestore-on-google-maps-using-jetpack-compose-9490c92c34da) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreGoogleMapsJetpackCompose).